# How to write this filter?

Tags: jquery

I want to count the number of elements ( including `select` and `input` texts ) having the `attribute` **data-validate-func** equals to **required** and who are filled with value. I tried this but I do not know about the filtering of filled value :

```
$("*[data-validate-func='required']").length;
```

So how to count them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to filter by a property, you can use the `filter()` method to achieve what you require. Try this:

```
var count $('[data-validate-func="required"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) !== '';
}).length;
```

Note that if you want to restrict this to `select` and `input` elements only, you would need to amend the primary selector:

```
var count $('select[data-validate-func="required"], input[data-validate-func="required"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) !== '';
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = $("[data-validate-func='required']").filter(function(){
   return $(this).val().length;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `*` from

```
$("*[data-validate-func='required']").length;
```

to

```
$("[data-validate-func='required']").length;
```

Or if you just want select and input:

```
$("select[data-validate-func='required'], input[data-validate-func='required']").length;
```